# Ionic2 swipable tab with content swipe

Tags: ionic2, ionic2-tabs

I have tried swipable and scrollable tabs in Ionic1 where i used slide-box and delgates but I want to integrate it in Ionic2. My requirement is

[image: this].

I have already tried https://github.com/SinoThomas/Ionic2-ScrollableTabs but it is only swiping tabs.

Comment: Unfortunately, SO is not a free coding service and questions asking for external resources are out of scope. Either way, this is not the right forum for this question.

Comment: Did you check my question @MadPhysicist. What is wrong in it ? Am i doing wrong to ask something .If anybody know this then reply otherwise no need to reply

Comment: You posit a requirement, no code and no effort on your part. Please look up the official site rules if you think my initial comment was made up just to be rude instead of being meant literally.

Comment: Fine ,no problem but i worked with that git hub code . It is working fine but only tab is swiping here .full code is same as defined in that git

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the best Solution at the moment. Please look into this!

Ionic 2 Forum:
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-2-swipeable-tabs-are-now-here/84266
GitHub:
https://github.com/zyramedia/ionic2-super-tabs-example

Comment: Thanks. I have used this but i want to scroll tabs also . I have put my issue there https://github.com/zyramedia/ionic2-super-tabs-example/issues/2 :(

Comment: But i want to use it asap in my office project :(

Comment: Well you have to correspondend with the creators of the super tabs. Show them this link: https://github.com/SinoThomas/Ionic2-ScrollableTabs in your GitHub Issue so they will know and understand better what you want. If you have luck they will add it soon.

Comment: As you can see they uptadted it! You can now scroll Tabs too if you want to :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make some swiped tabs under a selected tab , you can try this use to use this tutorial 
swiped tabs in ionic 3

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mlwVsr0_iO8&t=2s
[image]